# In Read The Docs theme build with Sphinx, how to remove extra space after image inclusion

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, read-the-docs

I am using Sphinx with the Read The Docs theme to build a website.

I include images on the right of a text with:

```
.. figure:: fig/image.png
:width: 150px
:align: right

Lorem ipsum ...
```

The result obtained after compilation is: [image: Example]

My question is: how to remove the extra blank line after the image.png?

Comment: @Timotheus.Kampik maybe you can help me again?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Blendify [same question on GitHub](https://github.com/rtfd/sphinx_rtd_theme/issues/352), in the `theme.css` file, the `margin-bottom` have to be set to `0px` instead of `24px`. In that particular case, it is:

```
.section>a>img{margin-bottom:0px}
```